# Joining 2 sales tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, report

I've 2 tables `transaction` & `cash`.
I'll raise invoice on day 1, the cash may be received in one or more installments.

My tables look as follows:

Transaction table:

```
date       | customerid | inv_amt 
---------------------------------
2014-12-12 | 1001       | 1000
2014-12-12 | 1002       | 2000
```

Cash table:

```
date       | customerid | rec_amt 
---------------------------------
2014-12-12 | 1001       | 1000
2014-12-12 | 1002       | 1000
2014-12-13 | 1002       |  500
2014-12-13 | 1003       | 2000
```

I want to join as follows:

```
date       | customerid  | Inv_amt | cash
-----------------------------------------
2014-12-12 | 1001        | 1000    | 1000
2014-12-12 | 1002        | 2000    | 1000
2014-12-13 | 1002        | Null    |  500
2014-12-13 | 1003        | Null    | 2000
```

Comment: Does the joined table have 3 fields or 4 fields?

Comment: 4 feilds i.e., date | customer | inv_amt | cash

Comment: I think for the result table, second row, for Inv_amt it should be 2000 instead of 1000, since the transaction table shows 2000, am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT    a.dates, a.customerid, sum(a.inv_amt), sum(b.rec_amt)
FROM      trans a
LEFT JOIN cash b ON a.dates = b.dates AND a.customerid = b.customerid
GROUP BY  a.dates, a.customerid

UNION

SELECT    b.dates, b.customerid, sum(a.inv_amt), sum(b.rec_amt)
FROM      trans a
RIGHT JOIN cash b ON a.dates = b.dates AND a.customerid = b.customerid
GROUP BY  b.dates, b.customerid
```

Comment: i'm not getting it right when only cash transaction is there. see the last 2 rows of the result table in my question.

Comment: how to use where date='2014-12-13'?  its giving multiplied Totals

Comment: I don't get what you meant. If you want to use `where date...` you can put that before the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: if u don't mind plz give me solution in MySql. i'm using Mysql

Comment: Please see updated answer. If you want the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c7e3/3

Answer (score 0):

You can join your table in Mysql using [This](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) .Try out group by class for finding whether the instalment amount is less than the total amount to be paid. Check out Nested queries or functions for that.

Comment: My purpose of joining the tables to know the total sale and total cash received on a particular day by 'CUSTOMERID'